# How to use the key (defined from lists items key) as prop on my Modal

Tags: reactjs

I have defined the Key in my code `key={item.id}` when mapping through `reposit` list and I am trying to use it as a prop in my  here `{openModal && <Modal repo={reposit} my_key={key} setOpenModal={setOpenModal}/> }` but it doesn't seems to work. Someone can explain to me how can I access to the key on my Modal by using it as a prop ?

Here is the part of the code :

```
      <List.Item>
              <List.Content>            
                    
                    {reposit.map((item) => (  
                      <li key={item.id} onClick={() => {setOpenModal(true)}}>
                          <i className="folder icon" /> {item.name}
                      </li>
                      ))}
                    
                  {openModal && <Modal repo={reposit} my_key={key} setOpenModal={setOpenModal}/> } 
              </List.Content>
     </List.Item>
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you elaborate on _it doesn't seem to work_. What are you expecting, and what is happening? Why do you believe `Modal` should have anything to do with the `li` tag inside the loop? If you explain what are you trying to achieve rather than your solution, it would be easier to help.

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')

Here is the TypeError.

What I am trying to do is to use it as a prop on my <Modal/> element and here is the code part on my `<Modal/>`


`<button onClick={() => {props.setOpenModal(false)}} class="mini ui red button" > X </button>  
          <div className="title"> 
            <h1> {props.repo[props.my_key].name} </h1>            
          </div>`

Comment: Well `key` prop is for the `li` element. That is not a variable to reuse. What are you trying to achieve by passing `my_key={key}` to the `Modal`?

Comment: on click store the key in the state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use state to keep track the key for the clicked list item like below:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [myKey, setMyKey] = useState();

  return (
    <List.Item>
      <List.Content>
        {reposit.map((item) => (
          <li
            key={item.id}
            onClick={() => {
              setMyKey(item.id);
              setOpenModal(true);
            }}
          >
            <i className="folder icon" /> {item.name}
          </li>
        ))}

        {openModal && (
          <Modal repo={reposit} myKey={myKey} setOpenModal={setOpenModal} />
        )}
      </List.Content>
    </List.Item>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The li key attribute is only defined within the li element, it is not accessible outside of it.  Your modal is not a child of the li element so it can't be accessed in the way you are trying.  You have to pass item.id to the modal through the li onClick function.  One way would be to create state to keep track of what key should be passed to the modal, and change it within the onclick function.

```
const [modalKey, setModalKey] = useState()

const openModal = (key) => {
  setModalKey(key)
  setOpenModal(true)
}

...

<List.Item>
        <List.Content>            
                    
                    {reposit.map((item) => (  
                      <li key={item.id} onClick={() => openModal(item.id)}>
                          <i className="folder icon" /> {item.name}
                      </li>
                      ))}
                    
                  {openModal && <Modal repo={reposit} my_key={modalKey} setOpenModal={setOpenModal}/> } 
        </List.Content>
</List.Item>
```